# Firebase: Block child function with security rules

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following structure and rules for my database and my goal is to disallow user to get the name of the children by the child() function, even if there is no sign up. What I mean is everybody who knows the name of the child is permitted to write, but my problem is that everybody could see the names of the children by the child function.

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Structure:

```
{
  "collaborate" : {
    "xwkmM76Irf" : {
      "css" : "",
      "html" : "",
      "js" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

Forbidden:

```
firebase.database().ref('collaborate').once(
    'value', 
    function($snapshot){ 
        ...
    }
);
```

Allowed:

```
firebase.database().ref('collaborate/'+$id).once(
    'value', 
    function($snapshot){ 
        ...
    }
);
firebase.database().ref('collaborate/'+$id).set({
 ...
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of showing a depiction of your JSON structure, show a representative snippet of the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It won't help you its about security rules ...

Comment: Now with the JSON that you shared, can you give the code for one operation that you'd like to allow and one operation that you'd like to disallow? (I'm trying to get to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, because I'm not clear on what your goal or problem is)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok thanks for helping.I will try my best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow reading on child nodes by using a `$` variable:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "collaborate": {
      "$collaborateId": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Rules that start with a `$` are applies to each child node in that location.

So with the above rules, you can read any existing child node (but not get a list of child nodes by listening on `/collaborate`). And you can write new child nodes (or overwrite existing ones, one at a time).